# Can I use GDB to debug a running process?

Tags: linux, debugging, gdb

Under linux, can I use GDB to debug a process that is currently running?

Answer (score 112, accepted):

Yes.  Use the `attach` command.  Check out [this link](https://ftp.gnu.org/old-gnu/Manuals/gdb/html_node/gdb_22.html) for more information.  Typing `help attach` at a GDB console gives the following:

> ```
> (gdb) help attach
> ```

Attach to a process or file outside of GDB.
This command attaches to another target, of the same type as your last
"`target`" command ("`info files`" will show your target stack).
The command may take as argument a process id, a process name
(with an optional process-id as a suffix), or a device file.
For a process id, you must have permission to send the process a signal,
and it must have the same effective uid as the debugger.
When using "`attach`" to an existing process, the debugger finds the
program running in the process, looking first in the current working
directory, or (if not found there) using the source file search path
(see the "`directory`" command).  You can also use the "`file`" command
to specify the program, and to load its symbol table.

---

NOTE: You may have difficulty attaching to a process due to [improved security in the Linux kernel](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/security/Yama.txt) - for example attaching to the child of one shell from another.

You'll likely need to set `/proc/sys/kernel/yama/ptrace_scope` depending on your requirements. Many systems now default to `1` or higher.

```
The sysctl settings (writable only with CAP_SYS_PTRACE) are:

0 - classic ptrace permissions: a process can PTRACE_ATTACH to any other
    process running under the same uid, as long as it is dumpable (i.e.
    did not transition uids, start privileged, or have called
    prctl(PR_SET_DUMPABLE...) already). Similarly, PTRACE_TRACEME is
    unchanged.

1 - restricted ptrace: a process must have a predefined relationship
    with the inferior it wants to call PTRACE_ATTACH on. By default,
    this relationship is that of only its descendants when the above
    classic criteria is also met. To change the relationship, an
    inferior can call prctl(PR_SET_PTRACER, debugger, ...) to declare
    an allowed debugger PID to call PTRACE_ATTACH on the inferior.
    Using PTRACE_TRACEME is unchanged.

2 - admin-only attach: only processes with CAP_SYS_PTRACE may use ptrace
    with PTRACE_ATTACH, or through children calling PTRACE_TRACEME.

3 - no attach: no processes may use ptrace with PTRACE_ATTACH nor via
    PTRACE_TRACEME. Once set, this sysctl value cannot be changed.
```

Comment: does this also work for a pid of a process on a remote target?

Comment: You have to run a debug server on the remote target then; after that it should be the same.

Comment: The flag may be changed using `echo 0 | sudo tee /proc/sys/kernel/yama/ptrace_scope`.

Comment: Alternatively `sudo setcap CAP_SYS_PTRACE=+eip /usr/bin/gdb` to avoid the error "ptrace: Operation not permitted". See also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19215177/how-to-solve-ptrace-operation-not-permitted-when-trying-to-attach-gdb-to-a-pro).

Answer (score 153):

You can attach to a running process with `gdb -p PID`.

Answer (score 34):

Yes.  You can do:

```
gdb program_name program_pid
```

A shortcut would be (assuming only one instance is running):

```
gdb program_name `pidof program_name`
```

Comment: I don't know what that does but it sure as hell doesn't work for me. It says that <program_pid> does not exist.

Comment: I find that this works best as it loads the symbol table in addition to attaching to the process. It should be noted that `program_name` works if you are in the same directory as the binary. I think a path to the binary would work if you are in a different directory.

Comment: Didn't you forget the `-p` in front of `program_id`? Also, it might be necessary to run gdb with sudo to attach to a running process.

Comment: Can't withdraw my upvote.

Answer (score 16):

The command to use is **`gdb attach pid`** where pid is the process id of the process you want to attach to.

Comment: That's a misuse of gdb arguments. The manual said that the 2nd argument should be a filename, but when <pid> is supplied, gdb ignored the filename. (Equivalent to `gdb -p <pid>`)

Answer (score 10):

Easiest way is to provide the *process id*.

```
gdb -p `pidof your_running_program_name`
```

Please get the full list of option in `man gdb` command.

In case there are multiple process for the same program running, then the following command will list the processes.

```
ps -C program -o pid h
<number>
```

Then the output *process id* (number) can be used as argument to gdb.

```
gdb -p <process id>
```

Answer (score 4):

Yes you can. Assume a process `foo` is running...

```
ps -elf | grep foo

look for the PID number

gdb -a {PID number}
```

Comment: What distribution are you running on? Using a recent version of Fedora, 'gdb -a' prints an "option -a is ambiguous" error.

Comment: the official argument is -p/--pid

Answer (score 3):

If one want to attach a process, this process must have the same owner. The root is able to attach to any process.

Answer (score 2):

ps -elf doesn't seem to show the PID.
I recommend using instead:

```
ps -ld | grep foo
gdb -p PID
```