# How to attach a process in gdb

Tags: unix, gdb

I have a simple C program that forks a process and then runs an executable.

I want to attach the child process to gdb.

I run the main program in a console and open another console to find the pid of the child process, then I start gdb with the following command:

```
gdb attach 12271
```

where `12271` is the child process id, but the attach fails with:

```
No such file or directory.
```

Any idea why?

Comment: i don't think attach is a command line argument.  you can use it once gdb is already running.  this guy has a good tutorial: http://dirac.org/linux/gdb/06-Debugging_A_Running_Process.php

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I use GDB to debug a running process?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2308653/can-i-use-gdb-to-debug-a-running-process)

Answer (score 140, accepted):

Try one of these:

```
gdb -p 12271
gdb /path/to/exe 12271

gdb /path/to/exe
(gdb) attach 12271
```

Answer (score 23):

The first argument should be the path to the executable program.  So

```
gdb progname 12271
```

Answer (score 7):

With a running instance of `myExecutableName` having a PID `15073`:

hitting <kbd>Tab</kbd> **twice** after `$ gdb myExecutableName`  in the command line will automagically autocompletes to:

```
$ gdb myExecutableName 15073
```

and will attach gdb to this process. That's nice!