# Stop a script running process and get the blocked code

Tags: python, process, ps

I have a python script that is running on my machine like this:

```
  PID USER      PR  NI  VIRT  RES  SHR S %CPU %MEM    TIME+  COMMAND                                                                                                                                       
 1018 root      24   0 98836 9108 3352 S  0.0  0.1   0:00.03 python /usr/mine.py
```

This process has been running all day, while it is supposed to run for a few seconds and then to stop.

I wonder if there is a way, to get the current point of the code that is being executed, which is the point that the script is stuck.

Comment: I found a helpful comment here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/147114/1067688

Answer (score 0):

You can attach using gdb and get a backtrace.  It may or may not give you something easily discernible depending on what debug symbols you may or may not have installed.

Something like:

```
>>> gdb -p 1018
(gdb) bt
```

More info here:

[How to attach a process in gdb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14370972/how-to-attach-a-process-in-gdb)

[Backtraces](http://ftp.gnu.org/old-gnu/Manuals/gdb/html_node/gdb_42.html)

[Debugging Python in gdb](https://wiki.python.org/moin/DebuggingWithGdb)