# gdb attach to process error: could not open as an executable file

Tags: linux, gdb

when I use gdb to attach to a running process, gdb output "Unknown error 18446744073709551615":

```
gdb attach 13334             
GNU gdb (GDB) 7.11
Copyright (C) 2016 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <gnu link>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.  Type "show copying"
and "show warranty" for details.
This GDB was configured as "x86_64-pc-linux-gnu".
Type "show configuration" for configuration details.
For bug reporting instructions, please see: <gnu link>.
Find the GDB manual and other documentation resources online at: <gnu link>.
For help, type "help".
Type "apropos word" to search for commands related to "word"...
attach: No such file or directory.
Attaching to process 13334
"target:****the bin file full path***": could not open as an executable file: Unknown error 18446744073709551615.
```

I have checked the similar usage at:  [How to attach a process in gdb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14370972/how-to-attach-a-process-in-gdb)

however, when I attach it like:

> gdb path_to_exe pid

it reports more error:
Error while mapping shared library sections:
Could not open `target:/lib64/tls/libpthread.so.0' as an executable file: Unknown error 18446744073709551615
Error while mapping shared library sections:
Could not open`target:/lib64/libuuid.so.1' as an executable file: Unknown error 18446744073709551615
Error while mapping shared library sections:
Could not open `target:/usr/lib64/libz.so.1' as an executable file: Unknown error 18446744073709551615
Error while mapping shared library sections:
Could not open`target:/usr/lib64/libglib-2.0.so.0' as an executable file: Unknown error 18446744073709551615
Error while mapping shared library sections:
Could not open `target:/lib64/libcrypto.so.4' as an executable file: Unknown error 18446744073709551615
Error while mapping shared library sections:
Could not open`target:/usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6' as an executable file: Unknown error 18446744073709551615
....

Any tip?

Comment: thanks Mark, and I checked the link and found it is not the same problem.

Comment: Problem solved: I have two gdb installed, one is in /usr/bin/gdb, but the "gdb" was mapped to another gdb installed in a different location, then it could not find the glib files at start.