# Debugging Windows service built with mingw/msys2

Tags: c++, windows, debugging, mingw, msys2

Having one heck of a time debugging a crash in a Windows Service that I've build with QT and Boost Logger on Windows using MSYS2 environment. The main issue really comes when I stop the program right before exit. The program just doesn't exist successfully and throws one of these bad boys:

[image: Windows crack info]

If I was running it in gdb it might be a different story. I open the crash dump in windbg and get some info, but since the symbols aren't exported it's really cryptic.

[image: WinDBG image]

I see some issues when my program (called service) is calling the log. But I can't do much here in the way of where or what. How can I get something useful so I could finally solve this issue?

Thanks so much!

Comment: I'd love a comment  for the downvote. I'm really not asking you to debug my code. I just want to learn how to do it myself. If the way I'm asking is awful, let me know!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like the easiest and most natural way was to attach gdb to the running process. I simply ran msys2 as Administrator, then ran the command

`gdb service.exe -p [processID]`

Task manager gave me the process ID. As soon as the process was attached I just used the command

`continue`

to get it to continue running. Then I let it crash and gdb gave me the backtrace perfectly.

I've searched a bit for this and this was much simpler than trying to get windbg to read the symbols generated by g++ or read the assembly code. Hope this helps somebody having the same issue.

**References:**

[How to attach a process in gdb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14370972/how-to-attach-a-process-in-gdb)