# How to solve "ptrace operation not permitted" when trying to attach GDB to a process?

Tags: c, linux, debugging, gdb, strace

I'm trying to attach to a program with [GDB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Debugger) but it returns:

> Attaching to process 29139
> Could not attach to process.  If your uid matches the uid of the target
> process, check the setting of /proc/sys/kernel/yama/ptrace_scope, or try
> again as the root user.  For more details, see /etc/sysctl.d/10-ptrace.conf
> ptrace: Operation not permitted.

gdb-debugger returns:

> Failed to attach to process, please check privileges and try again.

strace returns:

> attach: ptrace(PTRACE_ATTACH, ...): Operation not permitted

I changed "kernel.yama.ptrace_scope" 1 to 0 and `/proc/sys/kernel/yama/ptrace_scope` 1 to 0 and tried `set environment LD_PRELOAD=./ptrace.so` with this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int ptrace(int i, int j, int k, int l) {
    printf(" ptrace(%i, %i, %i, %i), returning -1\n", i, j, k, l);
    return 0;
}
```

But it still returns the same error. How can I attach it to debuggers?

Comment: I sometimes have this problem even under root, when I try to attach a kernel process, i.e. one in `[` `]` (e.g. `[nfsd]`). Obviously, user space cannot attach kernel process.

Answer (score 258):

If you are using Docker, you will probably need these options:

```
docker run --cap-add=SYS_PTRACE --security-opt seccomp=unconfined
```

If you are using Podman, you will probably need its `--cap-add` option too:

```
podman run --cap-add=SYS_PTRACE
```

Comment: Even if the question was not mentioning Docker, I got here because of that. This solved for me and thank you for going beyond the question.

Comment: This worked for me running GCC 8.2 and GDB 8.1 in Docker

Comment: how can I do this when doing docker build instead of run? it doesn't seem to take those args? (i have a weird bug that only happens when using the Dockerfile)

Comment: This worked for me to get strace running in docker container

Comment: In docker-compose.yml I just had to add `cap_add: - SYS_PTRACE` (with new line after the colon) in my container specification.

Comment: In newer Docker version 18+, `--security-opt seccomp=unconfined` is no longer needed.

Comment: Is there a way to apply this option on a running docker container?

Answer (score 105):

This is due to kernel hardening in Linux; you can disable this behavior by `echo 0 > /proc/sys/kernel/yama/ptrace_scope` or by modifying it in `/etc/sysctl.d/10-ptrace.conf`

See also [this article about it in Fedora 22](https://rajeeshknambiar.wordpress.com/2015/07/16/attaching-debugger-and-ptrace_scope/) (with links to the documentation) and [this comment thread about Ubuntu](http://blog.mellenthin.de/archives/2010/10/18/gdb-attach-fails-with-ptrace-operation-not-permitted/#comment-141535) and .

Comment: the `echo ...` did only work in my case if I opened a root console first with `sudo -i` (`sudo echo ...` did not work due to the redirection symbol)

Comment: Some shell constructs are tricky to use in arguments to commands such as sudo.

Comment: When using sudo and redirection you can use `echo 0 | sudo tee /proc/sys/kernel/yama/ptrace_scope`

Comment: The comments on this site are better than most of the answers.

Comment: Or with `sudo bash -c "echo 0 > /proc/sys/kernel/yama/ptrace_scope"`

Comment: Works for docker containers as well.

Comment: How permanent is that `echo 0 > ...` change?  Does it go back to normal after a reboot or anything? And do I do this in the container or in the host?

Comment: @Wyck What host or container? This is for the Linux kernel. do it for the Linux kernel where you need it. No need for any containers.

Answer (score 20):

Just want to emphasize a related [answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/282185/628938). Let's say that you're root and you've done:

```
strace -p 700
```

and get:

```
strace: attach: ptrace(PTRACE_SEIZE, 700): Operation not permitted
```

Check:

```
grep TracerPid /proc/700/status
```

If you see something like `TracerPid:   12`, i.e. **not 0**, that's the PID of the program that is already using the [ptrace](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/ptrace.2.html) system call. Both `gdb` and `strace` use it, and there can only be one active at a time.

Answer (score 18):

I would like to add that I needed `--security-opt apparmor=unconfined` along with the options that @wisbucky mentioned. This was on Ubuntu 18.04 (both Docker client and host). Therefore, the full invocation for enabling gdb debugging within a container is:

`docker run --cap-add=SYS_PTRACE --security-opt seccomp=unconfined --security-opt apparmor=unconfined`

Answer (score 16):

As most of us land here for Docker issues I'll add the **Kubernetes** answer as it might come in handy for someone...

---

You must add the `SYS_PTRACE` capability in your pod's security context
at `spec.containers.securityContext`:

```
       securityContext:
          capabilities:
            add: [ "SYS_PTRACE" ]
```

There are 2 `securityContext` keys at 2 different places. If it tells you that the key is not recognized than you missplaced it. Try the other one.

You probably need to have a root user too as default. So in the other security context (`spec.securityContext`) add :

```
      securityContext:
        runAsUser: 0
        runAsGroup: 0
        fsGroup: 101
```

*FYI : 0 is root. But the fsGroup value is unknown to me. For what I'm doing I don't care but you might.*

Now you can do :

```
strace -s 100000 -e write=1  -e trace=write -p 16
```

You won't get the permission denied anymore !

**BEWARE : This is the Pandora box. Having this in production it NOT recommended.**

Answer (score 13):

Not really addressing the above use-case but I had this problem:

**Problem**: It happened that I started my program with `sudo`, so when launching gdb it was giving me `ptrace: Operation not permitted`.

**Solution**: `sudo gdb ...`

Comment: But note that `sudo gdb` will also not work if `echo 3 | sudo tee /proc/sys/kernel/yama/ptrace_scope` (https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/security/Yama.txt), and it won't see your `.gdbinit` scripts.

Answer (score 9):

I was running my code with higher privileges to deal with Ethernet Raw Sockets by setting set capability command in Debian Distribution. I tried the above solution: `echo 0 > /proc/sys/kernel/yama/ptrace_scope`
 or by modifying it in `/etc/sysctl.d/10-ptrace.conf` but that did not work for me.

Additionally, I also tried with set capabilities command for gdb in installed directory (usr/bin/gdb) and it works: `/sbin/setcap CAP_SYS_PTRACE=+eip /usr/bin/gdb`.
Be sure to run this command with root privileges.

Comment: The added capabilities are permanent unless you take them away with `setcap CAP_SYS_PTRACE=-eip /usr/bin/gdb` or `setcap -r /usr/bin/gdb`. See [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/303423/unset-setcap-additional-capabilities-on-excutable) for more.

Answer (score 4):

Jesup's answer is correct; it is due to Linux kernel hardening. In my case, I am using Docker Community for Mac, and in order to do change the flag I must enter the LinuxKit shell using justin cormack's nsenter (ref: https://www.bretfisher.com/docker-for-mac-commands-for-getting-into-local-docker-vm/ ).

`docker run -it --rm --privileged --pid=host justincormack/nsenter1`

> / # cat /etc/issue
>
> Welcome to LinuxKit
>
> ```
>                     ##         .
>               ## ## ##        ==
>            ## ## ## ## ##    ===
>        /"""""""""""""""""\___/ ===
>       {                       /  ===-
>        \______ O           __/
>          \    \         __/
>           \____\_______/
> ```
>
> / # cat /proc/sys/kernel/yama/ptrace_scope
>
> 1
>
> / # echo 0 > /proc/sys/kernel/yama/ptrace_scope
>
> / # exit

Answer (score 2):

Maybe someone has attached this process with gdb.

- ps -ef | grep gdb

can't gdb attach the same process twice.

Answer (score 2):

I was going to answer this old question as it is unaccepted and any other answers are not got the point. The real answer may be already written in `/etc/sysctl.d/10-ptrace.conf` as it is my case under Ubuntu. This file says:

> For applications launching crash handlers that need PTRACE, exceptions can
>    be registered by the debugee by declaring in the segfault handler
>    specifically which process will be using PTRACE on the debugee:
>      prctl(PR_SET_PTRACER, debugger_pid, 0, 0, 0);

So just do the same thing as above: keep `/proc/sys/kernel/yama/ptrace_scope` as 1 and add `prctl(PR_SET_PTRACER, debugger_pid, 0, 0, 0);` in the debugee. Then the debugee will allow debugger to debug it. This works without `sudo` and without reboot.

Usually, debugee also need to call `waitpid` to avoid exit after crash so debugger can find the pid of debugee.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using FreeBSD, edit `/etc/sysctl.conf`, change the line

```
security.bsd.unprivileged_proc_debug=0
```

to

```
security.bsd.unprivileged_proc_debug=1
```

Then reboot.

Answer (score 1):

If permissions are a problem, you probably will want to use gdbserver. (I almost always use gdbserver when I gdb, docker or no, for numerous reasons.) You will need gdbserver (Deb) or gdb-gdbserver (RH) installed in the docker image. Run the program in docker with

```
$ sudo gdbserver :34567 myprogram arguments
```

(pick a port number, 1025-65535).  Then, in gdb on the host, say

```
(gdb) target remote 172.17.0.4:34567
```

where `172.17.0.4` is the IP address of the docker image as reported by `/sbin/ip addr list` run in the docker image. This will attach at a point before `main` runs. You can `tb main` and `c` to stop at `main`, or wherever you like.  Run gdb under cgdb, emacs, vim, or even in some IDE, or plain. You can run gdb in your source or build tree, so it knows where everything is. (If it can't find your sources, use the `dir` command.) This is usually much better than running it in the docker image.

gdbserver relies on `ptrace`, so you will also need to do the other things suggested above. `--privileged --pid=host` sufficed for me.

If you deploy to other OSes or embedded targets, you can run gdbserver or a  gdb stub there, and run gdb the same way, connecting across a real network or even via a serial port (`/dev/ttyS0`).

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what you are doing with LD_PRELOAD or your ptrace function.

Why don't you try attaching gdb to a very simple program? Make a program that simply repeatedly prints Hello or something and use gdb --pid [hello program PID] to attach to it.

If that does not work then you really do have a problem.

Another issue is the user ID. Is the program that you are tracing setting itself to another UID? If it is then you cannot ptrace it unless you are using the same user ID or are root.

Comment: it attachs simple programs but i'm trying to attach a crackme file. it has anti-debug protection [like this](http://xorl.wordpress.com/2009/01/01/quick-anti-debugging-trick-for-gdb/).

Comment: @user2850750: I added another bit to the answer.

Comment: i'm trying it as a root

Comment: @user2850750: Alright. Well then, is it possible that gdb is somehow calling the ptrace function in your shared object? If you run gdb on a hello world program with your preload object does it also fail?

Answer (score 0):

I have faced the same problem and try a lot of solution but finally, I have found the solution, but really I don't know what the problem was. First I modified the ptrace_conf value and login into Ubuntu as a root but the problem still appears. But the most strange thing that happened is the gdb showed me a message that says:

`Could not attach to process.  If your uid matches the uid of the target process, check the setting of /proc/sys/kernel/yama/ptrace_scope, or try again as the root user.

For more details, see /etc/sysctl.d/10-ptrace.conf 
warning: process 3767 is already traced by process 3755 ptrace: Operation not permitted.`

With ps command terminal, the process 3755 was not listed.

I found the process 3755 in /proc/$pid but I don't understand what was it!!

Finally, I deleted the target file (foo.c) that I try to attach it vid gdb and tracer c program using PTRACE_ATTACH syscall, and in the other folder, I created another c program and compiled it.

the problem is solved and I was enabled to attach to another process either by gdb or ptrace_attach syscall.

`(gdb) attach 4416`

Attaching to process 4416

and I send a lot of signals to process 4416.  I tested it with both gdb and ptrace, both of them run correctly.

really I don't know the problem what was, but I think it is not a bug in Ubuntu as a lot of sites have referred to it, such https://askubuntu.com/questions/143561/why-wont-strace-gdb-attach-to-a-process-even-though-im-root

Answer (score 0):

Extra information

If you wanna make changes in the interfaces such as add the ovs bridge, you must use `--privileged` instead of `--cap-add NET_ADMIN`.

```
sudo docker run -itd --name=testliz --privileged --cap-add=SYS_PTRACE --security-opt seccomp=unconfined ubuntu
```

Answer (score 0):

From `man prctl(2)`:

```
PR_SET_PTRACER (since Linux 3.4)
    This  is  meaningful  only when the Yama LSM is enabled and in mode 1 ("restricted ptrace", visible via /proc/sys/kernel/yama/ptrace_scope).
    When a "ptracer process ID" is passed in arg2, the caller is declaring that the ptracer process can ptrace(2) the calling process as  if  it
    were  a  direct  process ancestor.  Each PR_SET_PTRACER operation replaces the previous "ptracer process ID".  Employing PR_SET_PTRACER with
    arg2 set to 0 clears the caller's "ptracer process ID".  If arg2 is PR_SET_PTRACER_ANY, the ptrace restrictions introduced by Yama  are  ef‐
    fectively disabled for the calling process.
```

To allow your program to be debugged by any process you can add the line:

```c
#include <sys/prctl.h>

int main(void)
{
    // allows any process to attach
    prctl(PR_SET_PTRACER, PR_SET_PTRACER_ANY, ...);
    
    // your code
}
```

This is useful if you don't know the PID of the debugging process. Furthermore, this only affects the security of your program, as opposed to setting `/proc/sys/kernel/yama/ptrace_scope` to `0`, which makes the entire system less secure.