# How can I tell a Python script to halt for debugger attach to process?

Tags: python, debugging

Is there a way to tell Python to halt execution at a certain point in a script and wait for a debugger to attach to the process?

Is there something similar to dot-Net's [`Debugger.Break()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.debugger.break(v=vs.110).aspx) in Python?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Different IDEs can use different methods for attaching to the process, however PyCharm, Eclipse, Visual Studio, and VS Code all use [pydevd](https://github.com/fabioz/PyDev.Debugger/tree/master) (VS/VSC via their Python plugin via [ptvsd](https://github.com/microsoft/ptvsd)) to provide their in-process debugger implementation. As a result, we can target those with one piece of code.

The idea is to wait until pydevd is imported and then stop at a breakpoint.

```
import sys
import threading

from importlib.abc import MetaPathFinder


class NotificationFinder(MetaPathFinder):
    def find_spec(self, fullname, _path, _target=None):
        if 'pydevd' in fullname:
            with t:
                t.notify()

t = threading.Condition()
sys.meta_path.insert(0, NotificationFinder())

with t:
    t.wait()

breakpoint()
```

Since pydevd creates `__builtins__.breakpoint`, this should work regardless of the Python version. I tested in PyCharm (Community Edition 2019.1.3). I started the script, attached with the "Attach to process" option in my IDE, and was able to attach successfully. The script then stopped at `breakpoint()` as expected.

Comment: This allows to attach to programs with a more complicated launch strategy, like ROS & ROS2!

Answer (score 1):

Install [ipython and ipdb](https://www.safaribooksonline.com/blog/2014/11/18/intro-python-debugger/). Afterwards you can just use

```
import ipdb
ipdb.set_trace()
```

And debug straight from the console.
You can also use pdb which comes [straight out of the box](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/pdb.html):

```
import pdb
pdb.set_trace()
```

Comment: ipdb is great, but pdb comes built-in with Python.

Comment: Still, I'm very interested in debugging from tools like PyCharm, and from my understanding pdb is limited to the console. Is there a way I could break and attach using a tool like PyCharm?

Comment: Well that would work differently.
You can look up tutorials for it like this one: https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/help/remote-debugging.html

Answer (score 1):

Here is another way you can wait for `pydevd`:

```py
while not (pydevd.connected and get_global_debugger().ready_to_run):
    sleep(0.3)
breakpoint()
```

In my setup `MetaPathFinder` was firing only the first time I would connect with `pydevd`. With a while loop you should be able to reconnect because you are not relying on `pydevd` import side effect.

Answer (score 0):

Improving on Timofey Solonin's answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/66841531/324204.

```
# ...

import pydevd
import time
while pydevd.get_global_debugger() is None or not pydevd.get_global_debugger().ready_to_run:
    time.sleep(0.3)
breakpoint() # breaks here

# ...
```

The improvement is to not use `pydevd.connected`. It is not defined in pydevd version 2.8.

Note that on Linux you may have a problem with having no permissions to attach to the process. [How to solve "ptrace operation not permitted" when trying to attach GDB to a process?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19215177/how-to-solve-ptrace-operation-not-permitted-when-trying-to-attach-gdb-to-a-pro)

Answer (score -1):

You can use my tool [madbg](https://github.com/kmaork/madbg) to do exactly that. Put this in your program:

```
madbg.set_trace()
```

This line will block until a debugger connects using:

```
madbg connect
```

`madbg` could connect from the same machine or over the network. It could also preemptively stop your process and attach to it.