# How to debug MPI with CLion?

Tags: debugging, mpi, clion

How to debug mpi program with Clion?
Executable is set mpirun, that's why I can not debug as usual, I think, so how to do it? Thanks

Comment: Are you running all MPI processes locally?

Comment: yes, i run it locally on processor with 4 cores

Answer (score 3):

As [Zulan](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37908993/2486641) already mentioned,

1. Add these lines before your breakpoint and rebuild your application (from [OpenMPI](https://www.open-mpi.org/faq/?category=debugging))

   ```
    int i = 0;
    while(0==i)
       sleep(5);
   ```
2. Launch your program from the terminal with `mpirun`

> `$mpirun -np 4 ./Application`

3. [Attach](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/clion/attaching-to-local-process.html) LLDB or GDB to a local process

> Run-> Attach to Process

4. Pause Program (the program will pause on `sleep(5)`)
5. Set `i!=0` and Resume Program
6. Happy debugging

You may need to connect to your other processes to set `i!=0` and continue debugging.

Comment: If your program fails due to ptrace: Operation not permitted, see: https://stackoverflow.com/q/19215177/9723204

Answer (score 1):

The current version of CLion does not directly support debugging MPI programs. The best you can do is to [attach to an individual process](https://blog.jetbrains.com/clion/2016/01/attach-to-local-process/), after it is launched with `mpirun`. You may have to delay the processes to give yourself enough time to attach to them. OpenMPI describes [a few tricks how to do so](https://www.open-mpi.org/faq/?category=debugging#serial-debuggers).

It can be very tedious to debug a parallel application with serial deuggers. Searching for the one process out of many that has an abnormal value is alot of manual work. Generally you are better off using a parallel debugger such as DDT or totalview.

Comment: thanks, but when i tried to attach process, program failed with message      ptrace: Operation not permitted.
Debugger detached