# How can I create an RPM from a module and recursively create separate independent RPMs for the dependencies?

Tags: perl, rpm, packaging, cpan

Given a module how can I create an rpm of not just the module, but all the module's dependencies?

Start by creating a test module

```
$ module-starter --author "Evan Carroll" --email "me@evancarroll.com" --module Foo::Bar
Added to MANIFEST: Changes
Added to MANIFEST: ignore.txt
Added to MANIFEST: lib/Foo/Bar.pm
Added to MANIFEST: Makefile.PL
Added to MANIFEST: MANIFEST
Added to MANIFEST: README
Added to MANIFEST: t/00-load.t
Added to MANIFEST: t/manifest.t
Added to MANIFEST: t/pod-coverage.t
Added to MANIFEST: t/pod.t
Added to MANIFEST: xt/boilerplate.t
Created starter directories and files
```

Now I edit the `Makefile.pl`, and add [`Mojolicious`](https://metacpan.org/release/Mojolicious) as a prereq.

```
...
PREREQ_PM => {                                                         
      'Mojolicious' => '0'
....
```

Now I can run

```
perl Makefile.PL
make dist
```

But running,

```
$ sudo cpantorpm -y /tmp/yum /tmp/Foo-Bar/Foo-Bar-0.01.tar.gz
```

I get this,

```
error: Failed build dependencies:
        perl >= 5.006 is needed by perl-Foo-Bar-0.01-1.noarch
        perl(ExtUtils::MakeMaker) is needed by perl-Foo-Bar-0.01-1.noarch
        perl(Mojolicious) is needed by perl-Foo-Bar-0.01-1.noarch
```

That makes sense, but I want it to create RPMs for these requirements. I would like `Foo::Bar` to require an rpm that is also generated from cpan that represents Mojolicious, and for a build system to output two RPMs (one rpm for `Foo::Bar` which requires the also-provided `Mojolicious` RPM).

Comment: FWIW I tried this (without using `sudo`) and `cpantorpm` failed because it uses `strace` to monitor the output of running `perl Makefile.PL; make` and `strace` failed with  `/bin/strace: Could not attach to process...For more details, see /etc/sysctl.d/10-ptrace.conf: Operation not permitted`. See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19215177/2173773) for more information.

Answer (score 2):

That would be way too easy to get around the dependecy hell.  I would go for some project
like [cpan-dependecy](https://github.com/stanaka/cpan-dependency) .  Somebody already did
the work for you.

Here is how it works:

> 1) How to install Following CPAN modules are required.
>
> - CPANPLUS
> - RPM::Specfile
>
> 2) How to use To create a rpm of Linux::Smaps bin/cpan-dependency.pl --conf=config/conf.yml Linux::Smaps
>
> 3) conf.yml
>
> - filter_requires .. Remove specified requires from the package.
> - build_skip .. Skip to build the package.
> - build_requires .. Build&Install specified packages before building the package.
> - requires .. Add specified packages to the package's dependency.

You need to adjust [conf.yml](https://github.com/stanaka/cpan-dependency/blob/master/config/conf.yml) to satisfy your dependecies.

To build your project you would do the following:

`bin/cpan-dependency.pl --conf=config/conf.yml Foo::Bar`