# How to fix error "cannot run C compiled programs" when using ASAN

Tags: linux, configure, ptrace, address-sanitizer

**Issue**: running `configure` scripts work fine, the C compiler can be used and the generated programs run. As soon as ASAN is added the configure script complains that the generated programs cannot run.

```
./configure
checking for a BSD-compatible install... /usr/bin/install -c
checking whether build environment is sane... yes
checking for a thread-safe mkdir -p... /bin/mkdir -p
checking whether make sets $(MAKE)... yes
checking whether make supports nested variables... yes
checking for gcc... gcc
checking whether the C compiler works... yes
checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out
checking for suffix of executables...
checking whether we are cross compiling... no
checking for suffix of object files... o
checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... yes
...
```

vs.

```
./configure CFLAGS="-fsanitize=address -fsanitize=undefined -fno-omit-frame-pointer -fstack-protector" LDFLAGS="-fsanitize=undefined -fsanitize=address" --enable-debug
checking for a BSD-compatible install... /usr/bin/install -c
checking whether build environment is sane... yes
checking for a thread-safe mkdir -p... /bin/mkdir -p
checking whether make sets $(MAKE)... yes
checking whether make supports nested variables... yes
checking whether CFLAGS can be modified... yes
checking for gcc... gcc
checking whether the C compiler works... yes
checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out
checking for suffix of executables...
checking whether we are cross compiling... configure: error: in `/tmp/test-asan':
configure: error: cannot run C compiled programs.
If you meant to cross compile, use `--host'.
See `config.log' for more details
```

config.log shows:

```
configure:3653: checking whether we are cross compiling
configure:3661: gcc -o conftest -fsanitize=address -fsanitize=undefined -fno-omit-frame-pointer -fstack-protector  -fsanitize=undefined -fsanitize=address conftest.c  >&5
configure:3665: $? = 0
configure:3672: ./conftest
==9941==LeakSanitizer has encountered a fatal error.
==9941==HINT: For debugging, try setting environment variable LSAN_OPTIONS=verbosity=1:log_threads=1
==9941==HINT: LeakSanitizer does not work under ptrace (strace, gdb, etc)
configure:3676: $? = 1
configure:3683: error: in `/tmp/test-asan':
configure:3685: error: cannot run C compiled programs.
```

Comment: You should *not* add `-lasan` or `-lubsan` to `LDFLAGS`. They are libs, and should be added to `LIBS` if needed. However, they are not needed. Instead, add `-fsanitize=address -fsanitize=undefined` to `LDFLAGS`. The compiler driver will add the proper libs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message from the configure script is very confusing (there's no cross-compiling involved), the hint of LeakSanitizer is not much better (we don't do any debugging) but contains an important hint: ptrace.

As hinted in a [GDB + ptrace question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19215177/how-to-solve-ptrace-operation-not-permitted-when-trying-to-attach-gdb-to-a-pro) the issue is that the [Yama kernel security module](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/security/Yama.txt) was configured to prevent the use of ptrace by ASAN.

Similar, slightly more helpful messages can be seen when running in valgrind:

> error calling PR_SET_PTRACER, vgdb might block

To work-around this issue:

- option 1:
  run the configure script (and later tests) in an elevated shell
  (`sudo bash`)
- option 2 (on a local/secured machine [possibly a VM/sandbox]):
  allow ptrace for everyone
  `echo 0 | sudo tee /proc/sys/kernel/yama/ptrace_scope`

When doing so the configure script runs as expected and the generated programs abort on exit if there's any error found by the sanitizers.

Comment: MIght make sense to file an issue to make LSan warning more readable.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same issue when using "podman build" ("docker build" works). Adding ptrace as a capability is probably doable. But another workaround is to set `ASAN_OPTIONS=detect_leaks=0` (during `./configure` and `make test` in my case).