# Is there a way to run a docker container as sudo, if it was build on a non sudo base-image?

Tags: docker, gdb, fedora, sudo, ptrace

This might be a stupid question, but I am going to ask it anyways...

I would like to be a superuser in the container if I run `docker exec -it <container> /bin/bash`.

`<container>` is a container that is built on a fedora-base-image which seems to assign me a user with non-sudo capabilities.

**Question:** Is there a way to still become superuser in my new image, if it was based on such an image?

**Why do I want this?** I would like to run `gdb attach` in this container, which gives me `ptrace: Operation not permitted`. I already tried to do `docker run --cap-add=SYS_PTRACE --security-opt seccomp=unconfined --security-opt apparmor=unconfined` (compare [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19215177/how-to-solve-ptrace-operation-not-permitted-when-trying-to-attach-gdb-to-a-pro/46676868)), which did not work. So my next guess would be to try this as super-user, as recommended in the same post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

with `docker run` you can pass the user flag.

```
-u, --user string                    Username or UID (format: <name|uid>[:<group|gid>])
```

I believe the UID of root should be 0, so I think any of `-u root` `-u 0` `-u root:root` should work?

If you're building a Dockerfile you can also add `USER root` to your dockerfile to switch users.

Answer (score 0):

A quick workaround that also worked was to use a multi-stage build, start off as sudo in the first build, do `RUN sudo chmod +s /usr/bin/gdb` and then use `COPY` in the second stage to get gdb with permissions from the first stage.