# Qt Creator / gdb / remote debugging / cross compilation: solib-search-path not used

Tags: linux, gdb, qt-creator, cross-compiling, remote-debugging

I'm using Qt Creator 3.2.1 and gdb 7.6.2 (`powerpc64-fsl-linux-gdb` from [QorIQ SDK 1.8](http://www.freescale.com/tools/embedded-software-and-tools/run-time-software/linux-sdk/linux-sdk-for-qoriq-processors-v1.8:SDKLINUX)) for debugging cross compiled applications.

On my ppc64 test machine (Yocto) I run gdbserver: `gdbserver :666 /path/to/myapp`

Then I connect using Qt Creator on my x86_64 dev machine (Debian) to gdbserver. I've specified Kit (sysroot is `/opt/fsl-networking/QorIQ-SDK-V1.8/sysroots/ppc64e6500-fsl-linux`), the toolchain gdb, etc... This works so far. I can debug any application.

But if my application links dynamically to a library and I want to debug this library (`/path/to/libmylib.so`), gdb within Qt Creator fails to step into the breakpoints of *mylib*.

What I want to do **with Qt Creator** is **like this**:

1. Yocto: start the gdbserver
2. Debian: run `powerpc64-fsl-linux-gdb /path/to/myapp` and enter

   - `set solib-search-path /path/to/mylib/`
   - `target remote 192.168.120.211:666`
   - `break MyLibraryFunctionIWantToDebug`
   - `run`
   - `c`

Log:

```
GNU gdb (GDB) 7.6.2
Copyright (C) 2013 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.  Type "show copying"
and "show warranty" for details.
This GDB was configured as "--host=x86_64-fslsdk-linux --target=powerpc64-fsl-linux".
For bug reporting instructions, please see:
<http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/bugs/>...
Reading symbols from /path/to/myapp...done.
(gdb) show solib-search-path
The search path for loading non-absolute shared library symbol files is .
(gdb) set solib-search-path /path/to/mylib/
(gdb) show solib-search-pat
The search path for loading non-absolute shared library symbol files is /path/to/mylib/.
(gdb) target remote 192.168.120.211:666
Remote debugging using 192.168.120.211:666
(gdb) break MyLibraryFunctionIWantToDebug
Breakpoint 1 at 0x10001088: file /path/to/myapp/myapp.c, line 196.
(gdb) run
The "remote" target does not support "run".  Try "help target" or "continue".
(gdb) c
...
```

Research so far:

- [gdb has a bug in version 7.4](https://sourceware.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=13989) (I'm using 7.6.2 right now)
- I can put the `set solib-search-path /path/to/mylib/` command into [.gdbinit](https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/gdbinit-man.html). In Qt Creator every .gdbinit file is ignored. I've tried multiple locations, e.g. `~/.gdbinit`, `/path/to/myapp/.gdbinit`, *command line arguments* option in Qt creator: `-x ~/.gdbinit`, Tools > Options > Debuggers putting the command into every *additional* field. None works :-(
- I'm not alone with my question, see [here](https://forum.qt.io/topic/37120/qt-creator-3-0-gdb-additional-startup-commands-executing-too-late) or [here](http://www.qtcentre.org/threads/62865-How-do-I-set-solib-search-path-QtCreator)

Any ideas how to cross debug with gdb in Qt Creator when using shared libraries?

Comment: try to 'gdb attach pid'

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2308653/can-i-use-gdb-to-debug-a-running-process

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's changed with QtCreator 3.6 (what I'm using), but if I put the `set solib-search-path` command in the "Additional Attach Commands" fiend and only that field, I got it to work.

Granted, my case may not be fully applicable to yours as it's not a full cross-compilation, but a case of running GDB on a different version of Linux than my remote target runs.

Comment: I "solved" this using a (cross)compiled gdb(server) 7.10 :-/

"GDB 7.10 brings new targets, features and improvements, including:

   * Improved support for accessing shared libraries directly from
     the target system when debugging remotely." 

http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/download/ANNOUNCEMENT

Comment: Interesting. I don't have that option myself, at least not yet. However, it will be nice to have it in the future once our standard build and product distros are updated to have that version of GDB.

Comment: Well, I did the following: configure with /opt/gdb710 prefix and then something like "ln -s /opt/gdb710/bin/gdb /bin/gdb710" (+ same for gdbserver). That's okay for a temporary solution, where both versions of gdb(server) coexist.