Segfault when using a function defined in a separate file, but not when defined in the same file
I am trying to write some wrappers using the Python C API to work with NumPy arrays. If I write all my code in one file, the code works fine, tests pass, and everything seems great. If however I try and split the file into some headers, and a few different files, it segfaults, and on the surface of it I can't see why. Am I doing something wrong?
(PS - I am also trying to come up with a nice way of writing #define PY_ARRAY_UNIQUE_SYMBOL ... and #define NPY_NO_DEPRECATED_API NPY_1_7_API_VERSION only once, but struggle with multiple definition complaints, and suspect the right way to do this might better influence how I split up the various files and headers).
My Example
I am making a module which takes a numpy array, multiplies it by some factor, and writes the result into another array.
The files looks like:
dir/
├── module.c
├── module_example.py
├── module_examples.so
├── module_headers.h
└── module_implementation.c

The tests I want to run without segfaulting in module_example.py:
#!/usr/bin/env python
import numpy as np
from module_examples import foo
import unittest


class TestNumpyFloatWrappers(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_numpy_wrapper(self):
        a = np.arange(10, dtype=float)
        b = np.arange(10, dtype=float)
        foo(input=a, output=b, factor=3.0)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    unittest.main()

The function I want to define in module_headers.h:
#ifndef PYARV_MODULE_HEADERS_H
#define PYARV_MODULE_HEADERS_H

#define PY_SSIZE_T_CLEAN
#include <Python.h>
#define NPY_NO_DEPRECATED_API NPY_1_7_API_VERSION
#include <numpy/arrayobject.h>

PyObject * foo(PyObject *Py_UNUSED(self), PyObject *args, PyObject *kwargs);

#endif//PYARV_MODULE_HEADERS_H

The implementation in module_implementation.c
#include "module_headers.h"

PyObject *foo(PyObject *Py_UNUSED(self), PyObject *args, PyObject *kwargs)
{
    PyArrayObject *input_array;
    PyArrayObject *output_array;
    double factor;
#define N_ARRAYS 2
    PyArrayObject **arrays[N_ARRAYS] = {&input_array, &output_array};
    char *arg_names[] = {
            "input",
            "output",
            "factor",
            NULL};

    if (!PyArg_ParseTupleAndKeywords(args, kwargs,
                                     "$O!O!d:multiply",
                                     arg_names,
                                     &PyArray_Type,
                                     &input_array,
                                     &PyArray_Type,
                                     &output_array,
                                     &factor))
    {
        return NULL;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < N_ARRAYS; i++)
    {
        PyObject *array = *arrays[i];
        if (PyArray_NDIM(array) != 1)
        {
            PyErr_SetString(PyExc_ValueError, "Array must be 1-dimensional");
            return NULL;
        }
        if (PyArray_TYPE(array) != NPY_DOUBLE)
        {
            PyErr_SetString(PyExc_ValueError, "Array must be of type double");
            return NULL;
        }

        if (!PyArray_IS_C_CONTIGUOUS(array))
        {
            PyErr_SetString(PyExc_ValueError, "Array must be C contiguous.");
            return NULL;
        }
    }

    npy_double *input_buffer = (npy_double *) PyArray_DATA(input_array);
    npy_double *output_buffer = (npy_double *) PyArray_DATA(output_array);
    size_t input_buffer_size = PyArray_SIZE(input_array);
    size_t output_buffer_size = PyArray_SIZE(output_array);

    if (input_buffer_size != output_buffer_size)
    {
        PyErr_SetString(PyExc_ValueError, "The input and output arrays are of differing lengths.");
        return NULL;
    }

    NPY_BEGIN_THREADS_DEF;
    NPY_BEGIN_THREADS; /* No longer need the Python GIL */

    for (size_t i = 0; i < input_buffer_size; i++)
    {
        output_buffer[i] = input_buffer[i] * factor;
    }

    NPY_END_THREADS; /* We return the Python GIL. */

    Py_RETURN_NONE;
}

Trying to glue everything together in module.c, where the first commented out few lines crash with a segfault, and the others (where everything lives in just one big file) works fine.
/* // Gives a segfault when the tests run
#define PY_ARRAY_UNIQUE_SYMBOL EXAMPLE_ARRAY_API
#include "module_headers.h"
*/

/* // Works fine. 
#define PY_SSIZE_T_CLEAN
#include <Python.h>
#define PY_ARRAY_UNIQUE_SYMBOL EXAMPLE_ARRAY_API
#define NPY_NO_DEPRECATED_API NPY_1_7_API_VERSION
#include <numpy/arrayobject.h>

PyObject *foo(PyObject *Py_UNUSED(self), PyObject *args, PyObject *kwargs)
{
  //...
}
*/

static PyMethodDef example_methods[] = {
        {"foo", (PyCFunction) foo, METH_VARARGS | METH_KEYWORDS, NULL},
        {NULL},
};

static struct PyModuleDef example_module = {
        .m_base = PyModuleDef_HEAD_INIT,
        .m_doc = "Something is going wrong here.",
        .m_name = "examples",
        .m_size = -1,
        .m_methods = example_methods,
};

PyObject *
PyInit_module_examples(void)
{
    import_array();
    PyObject *module = PyModule_Create(&example_module);
    if (
            !module || PyModule_AddStringConstant(module, "__version__", Py_STRINGIFY(NPB_VERSION)))
    {
        Py_XDECREF(module);
        return NULL;
    }
    return module;
}

Attempting to debug the issue
Running through a debugger in Python just says:
..../python ..../module_example.py
process exited with status -1 (attach failed (Not allowed to attach to process.  Look in the console messages (Console.app), near the debugserver entries, when the attach failed.  The subsystem that denied the attach permission will likely have logged an informative message about why it was denied.))

Process finished with exit code 0


Have you tried to use a debugger to catch your crash and see when and where in your code it might happen?

So I've recently had to posts on tips for debugging C bindings shut down as opinion based or off-topic. I know how to debug Python, and I know how to debug C, but I have no idea about how to debug both at the same time. By various trial and error and bisecting a working solution and the broken one all I know is that it's now due to the file being split into headers, but beyond that I have no idea.

Do you have your compiler set with warnings on? At the maximum level they'll go?

Compiler is using debug mode and all warnings are on on. Using Clang, the only warning I am seeing is ld: warning: -undefined dynamic_lookup may not work with chained fixups

Same thing happens if I switch to gcc.

Compile with -g -fsanitize=address,undefined - You'll usually get a very informative message in runtime like that

No new information has come from adding the flags.

@oliversm Are you kidding? Did you get a segfault without any extra info? If so, I doubt you are using the newly compiled library/binary

@TedLyngmo I wish, deleted the shared object and build caches and built all from scratch in debug mode: [ 93%] Building C object misc/CMakeFiles/module_examples.dir/module.c.o cd /Users/oliver/ClionProjects/pyarv/misc && /usr/local/opt/llvm/bin/clang-18 ..... -g -O0 -fsanitize=address,undefined -Wall .... CMakeFiles/module_examples.dir/module.c.o.d -o CMakeFiles/module_examples.dir/module.c.o -c /Users/oliver/ClionProjects/pyarv/misc/module.c

Hmm, perhaps it's not in your code it segfaults. You are using some lib to glue the c++ and python code together I guess. Any chance you could recompile that with the same options?

See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2308653/can-i-use-gdb-to-debug-a-running-process re "Not allowed to attach to process".

@TedLyngmo no library, just the Python/Numpy C extension API (e.g. I am not using C++ and PyBind). I have been trying to recompile by hand without the build system, but just trying to dig out where everything lives on my system.

@AllanWind - This was my debugger baked into my IDE.

Did you try the sysctl change to see if you get better debug info?  I may very well be wrong.

Looks like it might have been from me not using #define NO_IMPORT_ARRAY. Will double check soon.

After going down a rabbit hole of trying to build everything by hand and reading more carefully through the documentation here about import_array, I discovered the significance of #define NO_IMPORT_ARRAY when using multiple files. The most important paragraph I repeat here (emphasis mine):

In order to make use of the C-API from another extension module, the import_array() command must be used. If the extension module is self-contained in a single .c file, then that is all that needs to be done. If, however, the extension module involves multiple files where the C-API is needed then some additional steps must be taken.
...
In addition, in the files that do not have the module initialization sub_routine #define NO_IMPORT_ARRAY prior to including numpy/arrayobject.h.

Adding the #define NO_IMPORT_ARRAY where needed solved the issue, where the module_headers.h file now reads:
#ifndef TESTING_EXAMPLES_BINDINGS_H
#define TESTING_EXAMPLES_BINDINGS_H

#define PY_SSIZE_T_CLEAN
#include <Python.h>

PyObject *multiply_into(PyObject *Py_UNUSED(m), PyObject *args, PyObject *kwargs);

#endif//TESTING_EXAMPLES_BINDINGS_H

and module_implementation.c:
// clang-format off
#include "module_headers.h"
#define NO_IMPORT_ARRAY
#define PY_ARRAY_UNIQUE_SYMBOL EXAMPLE_ARRAY_API
#define NPY_NO_DEPRECATED_API NPY_1_7_API_VERSION
#include <numpy/arrayobject.h>
// clang-format on

PyObject *
multiply_into(PyObject *Py_UNUSED(m), PyObject *args, PyObject *kwargs)
{
//...
}

and lastly module.c:
#include "module_headers.h"

#define PY_ARRAY_UNIQUE_SYMBOL EXAMPLE_ARRAY_API
#define NPY_NO_DEPRECATED_API NPY_1_7_API_VERSION
#include <numpy/arrayobject.h>

static PyMethodDef example_methods[] = {
        {"foo", (PyCFunction) (void (*)(void)) foo, METH_VARARGS | METH_KEYWORDS, NULL},
        {NULL},
};

static struct PyModuleDef example_module = {
        .m_base = PyModuleDef_HEAD_INIT,
        .m_doc = "Something is going wrong here.",
        .m_name = "examples",
        .m_size = -1,
        .m_methods = example_methods,
};

PyObject *
PyInit_module_examples(void)
{
    import_array();
    PyObject *module = PyModule_Create(&example_module);
    if (
            !module || PyModule_AddStringConstant(module, "__version__", Py_STRINGIFY(NPB_VERSION)))
    {
        Py_XDECREF(module);
        return NULL;
    }
    return module;
}

